# Repeat a test upon an AssertionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

There is the module [pytest-repeat](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-repeat/) which can be used to repeat the execution of pytest N times (the whole test suite).

However, I want to, upon an AssertionError, re-run that specific test again, instead of running the whole suit. So, how can I capture the AssertionError and programmatically call the same test function?

Comment: Does the test require some unreliable input or external connection? Can you modify the test so that other resource is entirely dependable?

Comment: @duhaime the issue is that  it tests that a specific number of clients are connected. So for example, it runs `assert total_clients == expected_clients`, where `total_clients` is the output of an API and `expected_clients` is a static value.. However, this `total_clients might not be real at a specific time, but some milliseconds later is correct.. That's because when a client is transitioning to a different state, it might report both states, and the API was coded so that total_clients = sum(clients per state). So I'm particularly interested in re-run the test to check that's correct.

Comment: so, yes, it depends on an unreliable input based on an external connection.

Comment: ok, I found a workaround to this, using `pytest-cache`. After a failed suite, just run `pytest --lf` and it will run the tests that failed in the previous execution. However, I'm keeping the question open because I'm interested in how to do this programmatically capturing the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`flaky` package](https://pypi.org/project/flaky/) provides a `@flaky` decorator. From the documentation:

```
@flaky(max_runs=3, min_passes=2)
def test_something_that_usually_passes(self):
    """This test must pass twice, and it can be run up to three times."""
    value_to_double = 21
    result = get_result_from_flaky_doubler(value_to_double)
    self.assertEqual(result, value_to_double * 2, 'Result doubled incorrectly.')
```