# Is there a way to overwrite the main loop in py.test?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

In `py.test` there must be a function that loops over each found test and executes them sequentially.

Is there a way to overwrite this function/loop?

Because I want to run the tests sequentially, as before, but run the failed tests again a second time (or a third time) to see if they might succeed on the second (third) try.

(Some background explanation: The system to test is a GUI application which depends on many different systems, and rarely some of them fail or does not behave as expected. When you have some of these tests it becomes quite likely that at least on test will fail. Therefore I want to repeat the failed test for a couple of times. Also, that system cannot be changed).

Comment: There's a plugin `pytest-rerunfailures` which does the job

Comment: Or look up documentation on conftest (from py.test). But a plugin seems better ;)

Comment: Sure a plugin is much better. I did not know that suh things exist...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repeat a test upon an AssertionError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50908236/repeat-a-test-upon-an-assertionerror)